# Slurm: how to use all cores available to the node?

Tags: queue, slurm, supercomputers

I'm working with a large computing cluster with a SLURM workload manager that has four different subsections: we'll call them C1, C2, C3, and C4. Nodes in C1 and C2 have 28 cores, whereas those in C3 and C4 have 40 and 52 cores, respectively. I would like to be able to use all cores per node, but when I submit a job to the queue, I have no idea to which subsection it will be assigned and therefore don't know how many cores will be available. Is there a variable in SLURM to plug into `--ntasks-per-node` that will tell it to use all available cores on the node?

Comment: Yes, the node assignment is random, unless your demands are too explicit. If you wish to use a specific node you can book or reserve the node with the help of your admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request a full node, with `--nodes=1 --exclusive`, you will get access to all CPUs (which you can check with `cat /proc/$$/status|grep Cpus`). The number of CPUs available will be given by the `SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE` environment variable.

But the number of `tasks` will be one so you might have to adjust how you start your program and set the number of CPUs explicitly, for instance with an OpenMPI program `a.out`:

```
mpirun -np $SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE ./a.out
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! I accepted your answer, but don't have enough reputation to upvote your reply yet. :(